# Apache is running on Port 80 but can't connect remotely

Tags: apache

I have Apache installed on Windows 7. It's running successfully - I can connect to it from the local host. The problem is that none of the other computers on the local wireless network don't connect.

I have configured the \apache\conf\httpd.conf to "Allow from all" and to "Listen 80"

I disabled the Firewall for Port 80

Also, the command netstat -abn shows:
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0: LISTENING

Can anyone think of a reason that prevents me to connect from another machine?

Comment: have you checked the access log file on the server? do you see the requests from the other machines?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick comments. @hovanessyan: I don't know where to check if requests are coming. I'm pretty new in this area.

Comment: @Userpassword: Can you please explain a bit more. I didn't understand what you suggest to do. Thanks.

Comment: @user1462159 well - use joojle to find where the access log files are...

Comment: OK, I found access.log, thanks for the Google tip :), and I don't see any request from the other machine.

Comment: From a computer that cannot connect -try to execute "telnet <ip of the Apache Machine> 80" and paste the output.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have two computers that don't connect and I ran telnet from both. One of them says: "connection failed" and the other opened a Telnet window (with the IP of the Apache machine in as a title) without any output.

Comment: My config:  Listen 127.0.0.3:80  ->  For access via localhos,  Listen 192.168.0.3:80  -> for access from all my network

Answer (score 0):

Try using the repair option on the firewall - sometimes the wizard there will add additional rules which resolve the issue.